# Run testng test on jenkins machine without eclipse installed

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I'v written a testng test in java (using eclipse) and now i want to run this test on a jenkins machine (windows server on amazon) without installing eclipse.
when i copy the project to the vm and trying to run using the command prompt these commands:

```
java -cp {project_path}\bin;{project_path}\lib\* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

i get:

```
[TestNG] [ERROR]
Cannot find class in classpath: testng.test
```

any ideas?
already tried to update the testng jar file to the latest version.